# NullPointerException when starting Activity through Intent in Unit Test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-intent, android-fragments

I am trying to create a unit test for my main activity.

The MainActivity.class contains an inner static fragment class, in this fragment is a button made from a TextView that launches another Activity in it's onClick method. I get a NullPointerException when I run a unit test. The code for the unit test is:

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<MainActivity> {

    private Intent mMainIntent;
    private MainActivity mMainActivity;

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }


    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mMainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        mMainActivity = startActivity(mMainIntent, null, null);
    }

    public void testButtonWithValidPostcode () {
        FragmentManager m = mMainActivity.getFragmentManager();
        m.executePendingTransactions();
        TextView mainButton = (TextView) mMainActivity.findViewById(R.id.mainButton);
        EditText textField = (EditText) mMainActivity.findViewById(R.id.mainPostcode);
        textField.setText("SE18");
        mainButton.performClick();
        Intent i = getStartedActivityIntent();
        assertNotNull(i);
        assertTrue(isFinishCalled());
    }
}
```

It crashes on the performClick() and when in the onClick method when running in debug mode it appears as though the Activity hasn't properly instantiated.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Here is the log output from the test:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:3957)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:3932)
at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1054)
at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1033)
at com.intuitivedesigns.restaurants.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:106)
```

Here is the onClick method in MainActivity.class line 106 is startActivity(intent);

```
searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String postCode = textField.getText().toString();
        if (postCode != null && SupportUtilities.isValidPostcode(postCode)) {
            Intent listViewIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RestaurantListActivity.class);
            listViewIntent.putExtra(POSTCODE_FLAG, postCode);
            startActivity(listViewIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whats in MainActivity.java at line 106?

Comment: startActivity(intent);

Comment: I don't see that piece of code in what your post. Post all the relevant code.

Comment: added it to question, thanks

Comment: you have a NullPointerException at line 106. startActivity(listViewIntent) call will not crash with that exception. Put some logs around line 106 and see where it stops.

Comment: It works when I run it normally though.. only the test fails and it's because the Activity doesn't seem to create properly, I just don't know why it doesn't.